# R: "label" a row based on conditions from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics

I have a data.table (A) that is over 100,000 rows long. There are 3 columns.

`chrom     start      end 
     1:  chr1   6484847   6484896 
     2:  chr1   6484896   6484945 
     3:  chr1   6484945   6484994 
     4:  chr1   6484994   6485043 
     5:  chr1   6485043   6485092
    ---

183569:  chrX 106893605 106893654
183570:  chrX 106893654 106893703
183571:  chrX 106893703 106893752
183572:  chrX 106893752 106893801
183573:  chrX 106893801 106894256`

I'd like to generate a new column named "gene" that provides a label for each row based annotations from another data.table which has ~90 rows (B). Seen below:

`chrom     start       end     gene
 1:  chr1   6484847   6521004     ESPN
 2:  chr1  41249683  41306124     KCNQ4
 3:  chr1  55464616  55474465     BSND
42:  chrX  82763268  82764775     POU3F4
43:  chrX 100600643 100603957     TIMM8A
44:  chrX 106871653 106894256     PRPS1`

If the row start value in data.table A is within the row start and end values of data.table B I need the row in A to be labeled with the correct gene accordingly.

For example the resulting complete data.table A would be

`chrom     start      end   gene
     1:  chr1   6484847   6484896   ESPN
     2:  chr1   6484896   6484945   ESPN
     3:  chr1   6484945   6484994   ESPN
     4:  chr1   6484994   6485043   ESPN
     5:  chr1   6485043   6485092   ESPN
    ---

183569:  chrX 106893605 106893654   TIMM8A
183570:  chrX 106893654 106893703   TIMM8A
183571:  chrX 106893703 106893752   TIMM8A
183572:  chrX 106893752 106893801   TIMM8A
183573:  chrX 106893801 106894256   TIMM8A`

I've attempted some nested loops to do this but that seems like it would take WAY too long. I think there must be a way to do this with the data.table package but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to do this in base R (or potentially using `data.table`), I would highly recommend using `GenomicRanges`; it's a very powerful and flexible R/Bioconductor library that's been designed for these kind of tasks.

Here is an example using `GenomicRanges::findOverlaps`:

```
# Sample data
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "chrom     start      end
     chr1   6484847   6484896
     chr1   6484896   6484945
     chr1   6484945   6484994
     chr1   6484994   6485043
     chr1   6485043   6485092", sep = "", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F);

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "chrom     start       end     gene
     chr1   6484847   6521004     ESPN
     chr1  41249683  41306124     KCNQ4
     chr1  55464616  55474465     BSND
     chrX  82763268  82764775     POU3F4
     chrX 100600643 100603957     TIMM8A
     chrX 106871653 106894256     PRPS1", sep = "", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F);

# Convert to GRanges objects
gr1 <- with(df1, GRanges(chrom, IRanges(start = start, end = end)));
gr2 <- with(df2, GRanges(chrom, IRanges(start = start, end = end), gene = gene));

# Find features from gr1 that overlap with gr2
m <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2);

# Add gene annotation as metadata to gr1
mcols(gr1)$gene[queryHits(m)] <- mcols(gr2)$gene[subjectHits(m)];
gr1;
#GRanges object with 5 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames             ranges strand |        gene
#         <Rle>          <IRanges>  <Rle> | <character>
#  [1]     chr1 [6484847, 6484896]      * |        ESPN
#  [2]     chr1 [6484896, 6484945]      * |        ESPN
#  [3]     chr1 [6484945, 6484994]      * |        ESPN
#  [4]     chr1 [6484994, 6485043]      * |        ESPN
#  [5]     chr1 [6485043, 6485092]      * |        ESPN
#  -------
#  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

Comment: Worked great! I don't have a ton of experience with GenomicRanges but this totally makes sense.

Comment: Glad to help @StephenWilliams . There are some great tutorials around if you want to learn more about `GenomicRanges` (see e.g. [here](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.pdf)); IMO you'll save yourself a great deal of future hassle if you familiarise yourself with the library;-)

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I've used this package in the past but my knowledge is very limited. I actually have some other columns in my data.frame that I did did not show for sake of simplicity and found that the makeGRangesFromDataFrame function worked perfectly to keep this metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [`GRanges`/`IRanges` solution by Maurits Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644366/3817004), there is an alternative `data.table` approach using *non-equi join* and *update on join*.

```
A[B, on = .(chrom, start >= start, start <= end), gene := i.gene][]
```

> ```
>     chrom     start       end  gene
>  1:  chr1   6484847   6484896  ESPN
>  2:  chr1   6484896   6484945  ESPN
>  3:  chr1   6484945   6484994  ESPN
>  4:  chr1   6484994   6485043  ESPN
>  5:  chr1   6485043   6485092  ESPN
>  6:  chrX 106893605 106893654 PRPS1
>  7:  chrX 106893654 106893703 PRPS1
>  8:  chrX 106893703 106893752 PRPS1
>  9:  chrX 106893752 106893801 PRPS1
> 10:  chrX 106893801 106894256 PRPS1
> ```

According to the OP, `A` and `B` are already `data.table` objects. So, this approach avoids the coercion to `GRanges` objects.

#### Reproducible Data

```
library(data.table)
A <- fread("rn         chrom     start      end 
     1:  chr1   6484847   6484896 
     2:  chr1   6484896   6484945 
     3:  chr1   6484945   6484994 
     4:  chr1   6484994   6485043 
     5:  chr1   6485043   6485092
183569:  chrX 106893605 106893654
183570:  chrX 106893654 106893703
183571:  chrX 106893703 106893752
183572:  chrX 106893752 106893801
183573:  chrX 106893801 106894256", drop = 1L)

B <- fread("rn    chrom     start       end     gene
 1:  chr1   6484847   6521004     ESPN
 2:  chr1  41249683  41306124     KCNQ4
 3:  chr1  55464616  55474465     BSND
42:  chrX  82763268  82764775     POU3F4
43:  chrX 100600643 100603957     TIMM8A
44:  chrX 106871653 106894256     PRPS1", drop = 1L)
```

Comment: You'll need to join on `chrom` as well AFAIU.

Comment: @Arun, you are probably right. Thanks for pointing out. I've amended the code accordingly.